# Syntaxnet C++ Api

Tags: syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

I have installed Syntaxnet and parsed few example files. I am planning to create a C++ application which uses Syntaxnet to parse the input document. I searched to find if I could use the Syntaxnet Net C++ API, but i couldn't find one. Can any one please give suggestions on how to use Syntaxnet as a API. Thanks in Advance.